# How to render validation errors of form partial - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, parameters, partials

I am building a custom blog. I have `posts` and `comments`.

I render comments through a partial on the show action of individual posts.

**posts controller**

```
 class Blog::PostsController < Blog::BaseController

  def show
    @post = Post.find_by_permalink(params[:id])
    @comment = Comment.new(:post => @post)
  end

end
```

**comments controller**

```
class Blog::CommentsController < Blog::BaseController

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment successfully created!"
      redirect_to blog_post_url(@comment.post)
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Something went wrong, try again. If problem persists please let our team know about it!"
      redirect_to :back
    end
  end

  private
      def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body,:name,:email,:user_id,:post_id)
      end
end
```

**show.html.erb**

```
<div class="row post-container">
  <div class="large-offset-1 large-7 medium-12 columns post-content">
    <h1 class="post-title"> <%= link_to @post.title, blog_post_path(@post) %> </h1>
    <p class="published-date"><em>Published on <%= l @post.published_at, format: :date %></em></p>

    <div class="post-body">
      <%= @post.body.html_safe %>
      <%= render partial: "blog/comments/comment", post: @post %>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="large-4 columns sidebar">
    sidebar
  </div>
</div>
```

**comments partial form**

```
<%= form_for [:blog,@comment] do |f| %>
  <%= render 'blog/shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :name %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :name,class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :email %><br>
    <%= f.text_field :email,class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <div class="field panel">
    <%= f.label :body, "Comment" %><br>
    <%= f.text_area :body,class: 'form-control' %>
  </div>

  <% if logged_in? %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :user_id, value: current_user.id %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.hidden_field :post_id %>



  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit "Create comment", class:"btn btn-danger btn-block" %>
    <a class="btn btn-warning btn-block cancel">Cancel</a>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

**error messages partial**

```
<% if object.errors.any? %>
  <div id="error_explanation">
    <div class="errors-alert text-center">
      The form contains <%= pluralize(object.errors.count, "error") %>.
    </div>
    <ul>
    <% object.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
      <li class="errors-alert-item text-center"><%= msg %></li>
    <% end %>
    </ul>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I tried to put validations on the comments model but it does not display them even though it correctly redirects back.

I know I have to use render instead of redirect but I do not know what to render. This is what I am trying to figure out since I do not have a render new action.

Comment: Simple way: use `gem weak_parameter` to validation params :D

Comment: i would prefer it if there is a solution without the use of gems.

Comment: What is the content of your `blog/shared/error_messages` or that is essentially the question?

Comment: @ItayGrudev i have put the content of error messages partial. its just a generic error generator that takes an object to show the errors specific to that object. in this case the comments object. The question is even though validation works, there are no error messages shown, propably because somewhere those error messages attached to the object are lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rewrite your `Blog::CommentsController` controller `create` action so it re-renders the form instead of redirecting to the previous page. This way the errors will be render on the page.

```
class Blog::CommentsController < Blog::BaseController

  def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    if @comment.save
      flash[:success] = "Comment successfully created!"
      redirect_to blog_post_url(@comment.post)
    else
      flash[:warning] = "Something went wrong, try again. If problem persists please let our team know about it!"
      @post = @comment.post
      render 'blog/post/show'
    end
  end

end
```

This way you are re-rendering the `show` action from the `CommentsController` and explicitly providing it with the correct `@post` so it is available in the view.